# Format field in apex:outputLink

Tags: outputlink

I need have the Amount field formatted like $`{0,number,##,##0.00}` in the URL within outputLink.  How can this be written?

```
<apex:outputLink value="http://www.bjp-studios.com/submit-payment/?tfa_6={!relatedTo.Amount}&tfa_13={!relatedTo.Id}">Pay Now</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Why would you care about number formatting in a link. That doesn't make a ton of sense.

Comment: The URL is receiving the value and displaying it to the user.  I want $125.00 instead of what is coming over now - 125.0

Where it makes sense or not, is it possible?

Comment: Do you have an `Apex` controller on your page? If so you have options. NB that you should be careful about escaping output pulled in from url parameters.

Comment: I don't.  This code is in a Visualforce email template.

Comment: Have you tried using `outputText` along with `params`? That would seem to be the only way of accomplishing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following manner

```
<apex:outputText value=" ${0,number,##,##0.00}" onclick="http://www.bjp-studios.com/submit-payment/?tfa_6={!relatedTo.Amount}&tfa_13={!relatedTo.Id}">
<apex:param value="{!amtFieldValue}"/>
```